# How to connect front-end application with database application in Hashicorp Nomad?

Tags: json, kubernetes, nomad

I am new to Hashicorp Nomad and trying to deploy one employee application, I have the code in kubernetes yaml file. Seperately I deployed frontend application with mongo database but I want to know how these two will contact each other because in k8s there is a concept of Selector but in Nomad what is available in behalf of selector and labels?

Answer (score 0):

Nomad does service discovery using HashiCorp Consul.
Check out this part of Nomad docs.
https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/integrations/consul-integration/#service-discovery

Answer (score 0):

There are few types of service discoveries in nomad.

- using Consul which is by default
- a simpler solution is provider="nomad"
- consul connect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).